# Create new django project in pycharm: "Remote path not provided"

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm

After creating a python docker container, I want to use it as my interpreter instead of Virtualenv. If I leave it empty it says "Remote path not provided". After typing something you see the warning on the screenshot.

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you haven't customized your docker image, the default Python location is `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I have customized my docker image. Just remembering, that I already created the project with "docker-compose run web django-admin startproject yourprojectname". Instead of creating a new project I just opened the existed project folder in pycharm and it seems to work now. I'll test around now.

Comment: I keep having the same issue. The only workaround I've found is to setup the project using virtualenv and then afterwards in project settings > project > project interpreter switch to Docker. For some reason this "remote project location" is not required there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fix it.  It is Jetsbrains domain to fix it.  It's a longstanding bug in Pycharm:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28097
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31823
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33662
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24427

You're expected to work around it.

1. by creating a virtualenv, even though you don't want it, then connecting the docker using other screens after the project is created.
2. by creating the project by just "open"ing the folder, then attaching the docker via the project dialogs.

One might wonder how, given that you can't use it, the option ever made it into the Create Project dialog, and why it's still there, but since we all work in software, we can surmise the answers for ourselves :-)